# BIOS Corruption

Tags: bios

I have a HP Pavilion g4-1058tx with a corrupt BIOS hence its bricked. Have spent the better part of last week researching on how to perform a recovery with no success. Anyone with any ideas?
p.s I'm currently using windows, I know this is a linux forum  but I've exhausted all avenues.
-Have BIOS editor.exe and phoenix tool(andy's tool) but have no idea on their use as i can't seem to find the files they require.
Kindly help.

Comment: Since you can't even run an operating system, this isn't a Linux question, it's a hardware question. We have no expertise regarding that. I've flagged your question to be migrated to our sister site [su], where PC hardware is on-topic (do not repost!).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about hardware and firmware, out of reach of Linux.

Comment: If its under warranty, get it repaired.  If its not under warranty, they can probably still fix it.'

Answer (score 1):

You could attempt a risky method, where you take a working bios chip place it in the computer, boot, remove the working chip, place the corrupt chip in the slot, flash, then reboot.

That's the only way I know of to fix a corrupt chip.